# Simple String Manipulation in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, email, string

This is probably quite a simple question, but I can't remember how to do it off hand.

I have an e-mail address of "foo@bar.com".

I want to grab the @ and everything after it and then I'll be adding a prefix to the front of the address as I go.

I'm just wonderng how I get hold of the @bar.com from the string?

I know I should know how to do this as this is a really simple operation.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple string operations for this:

```
email.Substring(email.IndexOf("@"C))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
"foo@bar.com".Split("@")(1)
```